# display coloumn in database with 2 condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as

```
bagian          lama

  3               9
  1               6
  4               7
  5               3
  2               2
  3               1
```

Now I would like this

```
bagian(1)  bagian(2) bagian(3) bagian(4) bagian(5) 
   6           2         1          7         3
```

what is right syntax in sql query
I have tried like this

```
   select WHEN bagian = '1' THEN cuti_tahun.lama  AS 1,WHEN bagian = '2' THEN cuti_tahun.lama AS 2,WHEN bagian = '3' THEN cuti_tahun.lama AS 3 from a
```

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select min(case when bagian = 1 then lama end) as bagian_1,
       min(case when bagian = 2 then lama end) as bagian_2,
       min(case when bagian = 3 then lama end) as bagian_3,
       min(case when bagian = 4 then lama end) as bagian_4,
       min(case when bagian = 5 then lama end) as bagian_5
from cuti_tahun;
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to add five conditions. Just mix the `ORDER BY` clause to sort and `GROUP BY` clause to group them. 
Try this and let me know what is the output:

```
SELECT MAX(`VAL` = CT.`bagian`) AS bagian(`VAL`),
FROM cuti_tahun CT
ORDER BY CT.`bagian` ASC
GROUP BY CT.`bagian`;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`VAL`), FROM cuti_tahun CT ORDER BY CT.`bagian` ASC GROUP BY CT.`bagian` LIMIT' at line 1

Comment: The quesry have issue in displaying the column title. If you can solve it somehow, this will be the best solution.